# What is Rudy doing there?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-jacket

In the movie The Jacket, Rudy claims that he's in the institution because he tried to repeatedly kill his wife.

Later, Dr Lorenson discloses that Rudy locked himself up in his house for two months and nearly starved to death before being brought to the institution.

So my question is, what is Rudy doing in an institution for the criminally insane if he's not a criminal to start with?